# Is this the right way to mimic where in list using Breeze.js?

Tags: odata, breeze

I am trying to build up a list of valid Id's and append them as a .Any predicate to the query.  I upgraded to the latest Breeze to get access to the filterQueryOp.Any and I wrote the following code.  Sadly it errors off.

```
var ids = [];
        listData.forEach(function (item) {
            ids.push(item.TicketId)
        });

        combined = combined.and(new breeze.Predicate('ItemId', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Any, ids));

        var result = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Tickets').using(itemManager)
        .where(combined)
        .execute()
        .fail(util.queryFailed);
```

Next is the query that is built up by Breeze

```
"(((StatusKey eq 65540) and (ParentKey eq 123743) and (Created ge datetime'2013-04-30T04:00:00.000Z') and (Created lt datetime'2015-05-01T04:00:00.000Z')) and (Open eq true)) and (ItemId/any(x6: 180170,180172,180173,180197,180198,180199,180200,180201,180204,180205,180206))"
```

We can see at the end there it has done something reasonable with the .Any, so far so good.

Then this result:

```
"')' or ',' expected at position 200 in '(((StatusKey eq 65540) and (ParentKey eq 123743) and (Created ge datetime'2013-04-30T04:00:00.000Z') and (Created lt datetime'2015-05-01T04:00:00.000Z')) and (Open eq true)) and (ItemId/any(x6: 180170,180172,180173,180197,180198,180199,180200,180201,180204,180205,180206))'."
```